# Where is Deathwing?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So I pretty much finished all Cataclysm quests and yet to see any quest that leads me to Deathwing.
This is probably a dumb question, but weren't we supposed to go kill him like we did to Lich King?
Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of now, Deathwing is flying around the world, killing unsuspecting (or very saavy and suspecting) AFK players to award them with the [Stood in the Fire](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=5518/stood-in-the-fire) achievement.

Similar to the Lich King in Wrath and Illidan in TBC, he is intended to be the ultimate villain of this expansion, and players can expect a final confrontation with him in a raid released in whatever the final content patch of this expansion cycle will be. Given past trends, that'll probably be a patch 4.3 or patch 4.4. Between now and then, there's the Twilights Hammer, an Old God, Deathwings kids, and a whole lot of angry Elementals to deal with, not to mention possibly some other big baddies we haven't seen too much of yet this expansion like Azshara perhaps.

Comment: And don't forget -- Ragnaros 2.0! By Fire be purged!

Comment: He's an Angry Elemental.

Comment: He's an *adorable* elemental.

Comment: He's a big elemental.

Comment: He's a hot elemental.